# How to always show one view in MVC4 App (for when I need to migrate DB)?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an MVC4 app - I'd like to somehow be able to lock down the app to only display some kind of "Under Maintenance" page for when I have to migrate the database.  I originally tried using Global.asax to always redirect, but this is unweildy as I have subdomains / tenants / localhost to take into consideration.

If I could keep the URL, but display the Maintenance view *always*, that would be awesome.  Can this be done with MVC4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup app_offline.htm or appoffline.htm. Once it is placed in the root of an asp.net/mvc application IIS will return the contents of the page to all requests, however, existing connection will more than likely receive a connection error.